# Are security groups replicated/copied when creating RDS read replicas in a different AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a security group attached to an RDS instance that allows port 5432 traffic from the EC2 instances.

The RDS instance has a read replica created in a different region.

From my understanding, AWS will take care of replication and add the necessary configuration by itself for replicating source RDS data to the read replica.

For me to be able to read data from the read replica, all I need to make sure is to allow incoming traffic to the read replica in the other region.

Are security groups copied over from the DB instance to the read replica?

Do I need to create a new security group for the read replica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to create a new security group for the read replica?

Yes.

You will need to configure a new security group for the cross-region read replica.

As per [Amazon RDS User Guide for cross-region read replicas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.XRgn.html#USER_ReadRepl.XRgn.Cnsdr):

> The read replica uses the **default security group**.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Correct me if I am wrong, so the default security group has all inbound rules open to all connections using this SG the AWS PRIMARY RDS will write to replica right?

Comment: You don’t need to manage SGs for replication to happen, AWS does that in the background - you deal with SGs for *your* access

Comment: @learner the most welcome :)